# updating rasbian fix missing error

Tags: raspbian

I have spent days on this but I have not solved this please help.

```
 93% [1 scratch2 46.3 MB/67.8 MB 68%]               37.3 kB/s 9min 37s Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf scratch2 armhf 0.22
   Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:c185b291d0491678db28038891fde358d095a7379073ae73ceb860bfa4d398e1
   - SHA1:dd08210cc7abb628988bcdb3c42fd0aaa18378ad [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d66ca0755ff4a2faf3b050f7993b98b7 [weak]
   - Filesize:67808084 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:97277ee1adc7f2e75b796bb78d4558bc181454cc9f9413d2eeb3cf5fe45b99c1
   - SHA1:98a7a2a56e2fa6f99e40abecb1da95e14e5d558a [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3c1a670b9bf0bd50a998e0d1c50df85c [weak]
   - Filesize:67808084 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 09:20:11 +0000
 Fetched 136 MB in 51min 13s (44.1 kB/s)                              
 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/ui/s/scratch2/scratch2_0.22_armhf.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
    Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:c185b291d0491678db28038891fde358d095a7379073ae73ceb860bfa4d398e1
    - SHA1:dd08210cc7abb628988bcdb3c42fd0aaa18378ad [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d66ca0755ff4a2faf3b050f7993b98b7 [weak]
    - Filesize:67808084 [weak]
    Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:97277ee1adc7f2e75b796bb78d4558bc181454cc9f9413d2eeb3cf5fe45b99c1
    - SHA1:98a7a2a56e2fa6f99e40abecb1da95e14e5d558a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:3c1a670b9bf0bd50a998e0d1c50df85c [weak]
    - Filesize:67808084 [weak]
    Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 09:20:11 +0000
 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

how can I solve the above error I have spent the whole day on it but I cannot get anything

Comment: Hi. What exactly are you trying to do and already tried? Have you tried the suggested `apt-get update` or `apt-get --fix-missing ...`? For the benefit of all please add this information to the question by editing it.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is a bit unclear. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=235226